# Start mysql automatically when running a Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I have created a Dockerfile to have a development environment on my computer with php7, mysql and some other library.

The apache service starts automatically when a run the container but I can't get the same results with mysql. The last sentence of my Dockerfile looks like this `CMD ["bash", "run.sh"]` and then in *run.sh* I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

PHP_ERROR_REPORTING=${PHP_ERROR_REPORTING:-"E_ALL"}
sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
sed -ri "s/^error_reporting\s*=.*$//g" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
sed -ri "s/^error_reporting\s*=.*$//g" /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
echo "error_reporting = $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
echo "error_reporting = $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND

chmod 0755 start.sh
sleep 1
start.sh

/bin/bash
```

That calls a file named *start.sh* that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Mysql
sed -i -e 's/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
service mysql start
```

It is divided in two files because I tested everything but I can't get it working. If I do a docker exec inside the container and I start mysql everything works fine.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I finish my dockerfile with ENTRYPOINT and the script I give is end by bash. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND` relatively early in the `run.sh` script. The thing about `exec` is that it does not start a sub-process of the shell, but it *replaces* the shell with a new process.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh):

> `exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]`
>
> If command is specified, it replaces the shell. No new process is created. The arguments become the arguments to command.

This means that your shell script will *not* continue running after invoking `exec`.

I could now suggest a number of ways to hack around this with Bash, but all of these will be (in my opinion) messy and difficult to maintain. If you want to manage multiple processes within one container (like Apache and MySQL), I strongly suggest having a look at process managers like *supervisord*. There's an [excellent article in the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/) that even uses a similar use case to yours as an example.

Answer (score 0):

start.sh is given with no absolute or relative path, like if it was in your PATH, is it ?

You could add some "echo 'I am actually called' > log.txt" at the beginning of start.sh to check if it's even called.